# Relation between Discriminant of an Order and J invariant

Tags: finite-fields, elliptic-curves, complex-multiplication

I am reading [this](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1985-44-170/S0025-5718-1985-0777280-6/S0025-5718-1985-0777280-6.pdf) paper (Section 4) here they want to construct an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{F}_q$ whose order has discriminant  $'x'$.

They do that in two steps :

1. Firstly they calculate the j-invariant of such specific curve.
2. Then from j-invariant they find the equation of elliptic curve (in Generalized Wiestrass form)

They say if $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}$ satisfy  $x=b^2-4ac$ then $j(\frac{b+i\sqrt{|x|}}{2a})$ will be the required j-invariant.

I tried to consider this elliptic curve as a lattice generated by $\{ 1,\tau\}$  and tried to find $\tau$ using the fact that *Endomorphism ring will send Lattice points to lattice points* but I am unable to conclude the result specified in the paper.